# OpenShift (Tomcat 7) - blank home page after adding dependencies to pom.xml

Tags: tomcat7, openshift

I've just created a new application on openShift and It's my first time to use openshift.
I'm using this cartidage -> Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0)
first the link to my application was loading the default openshift `index.html`

but after adding some dependencies to `pom.xml` file it shows a blank page in the browser ... I haven't touched any other file, just that file.
I tried manual restart and many other things to get it working but it just keep showing blank page to any directory I try to load.

these are the dependencies I added

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
<version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
<version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
<version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
```

the log shows no error after pushing the changes .. everything is fetched from maven and everything looks fine.
I even deleted the application and recreated another one and still have the same problem

Comment: pls hlp .......

Comment: How does your pom.xml look like? Maybe you have colliding dependencies. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25265629/tomcat-7-jersey-2-0-error. Do you have any errors in logs?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `org.glassfish.jersey.*`(I mean every sub packages like bundle, media and etc) version `2.25.1` and I decided to check version by version and realized that version **`2.23.1`** is the newest version that works on this cartridge.