# The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes

Tags: java, xml, servlets, jersey

I have read other posts that mention this problem but that did not fix the problem.

I am trying to use jersey API for JAX-RS. but I have not been able to deploy it successfully. 
I am using Eclipse IDE.
Also, I have added the required jars to java build path as well as lib folder.

1. asm 3.1
2. jersey server
3. jersey core
4. jersey servlet
5. jersey quickstart webapp
6. jsr311

web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>restful</display-name>
<display-name>RESTfulWebServiceExample</display-name>  
  <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>  
    <init-param>  
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>  
      <param-value>com.resttest.resttest</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
  </servlet>  
  <servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

resttest.java is as follows:

```
package com.resttest;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/calc")
public class resttest{

   @GET
   @Path("/add/{a}/{b}")
   @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
   public String addPlainText(@PathParam("a") double a, @PathParam("b") double b) {
       return (a + b) + "";
   }

@GET
   @Path("/sub/{a}/{b}")
   @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
   public String subPlainText(@PathParam("a") double a, @PathParam("b") double b) {
       return (a - b) + "";
   }

   @GET
   @Path("/add/{a}/{b}")
   @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
   public String add(@PathParam("a") double a, @PathParam("b") double b) {
       return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<result>" +  (a + b) + "</result>";
   }

   @GET
   @Path("/sub/{a}/{b}")
   @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
   public String sub(@PathParam("a") double a, @PathParam("b") double b) {
       return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<result>" +  (a - b) + "</result>";
   }
}
```

**Edit**: After I tried what has been suggested by bruno cesar, it still could not be deployed. Here is the stack trace:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: Unable to create resource
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.resource.SingletonFactory$Singleton.init(SingletonFactory.java:139)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$10.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:584)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$10.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:581)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.getResourceComponentProvider(WebApplicationImpl.java:581)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiateResource(WebApplicationImpl.java:658)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.initWadlResource(RootResourceUriRules.java:184)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:162)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1298)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:169)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:775)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1583)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5670)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5912)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2278)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1924)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentConstructor._construct(ResourceComponentConstructor.java:198)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentConstructor.construct(ResourceComponentConstructor.java:179)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.resource.SingletonFactory$Singleton.init(SingletonFactory.java:137)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlGeneratorImpl.createResponse(WadlGeneratorImpl.java:198)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generateResponse(WadlBuilder.java:395)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generateMethod(WadlBuilder.java:164)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generateResource(WadlBuilder.java:331)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generateResource(WadlBuilder.java:269)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generate(WadlBuilder.java:105)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlApplicationContextImpl.getApplication(WadlApplicationContextImpl.java:79)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlResource.<init>(WadlResource.java:77)
    ... 76 more

2015-05-16T00:14:44.297+0530|SEVERE: WebModule[/restful]Servlet /restful threw load() exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlGeneratorImpl.createResponse(WadlGeneratorImpl.java:198)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generateResponse(WadlBuilder.java:395)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generateMethod(WadlBuilder.java:164)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generateResource(WadlBuilder.java:331)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generateResource(WadlBuilder.java:269)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generate(WadlBuilder.java:105)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlApplicationContextImpl.getApplication(WadlApplicationContextImpl.java:79)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlResource.<init>(WadlResource.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentConstructor._construct(ResourceComponentConstructor.java:198)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentConstructor.construct(ResourceComponentConstructor.java:179)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.resource.SingletonFactory$Singleton.init(SingletonFactory.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$10.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:584)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$10.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:581)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.getResourceComponentProvider(WebApplicationImpl.java:581)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiateResource(WebApplicationImpl.java:658)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.initWadlResource(RootResourceUriRules.java:184)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:162)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1298)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:169)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:775)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1583)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5670)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5912)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2278)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1924)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

2015-05-16T00:14:44.297+0530|SEVERE: Startup of context /restful failed due to previous errors
2015-05-16T00:14:44.297+0530|SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5920)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2278)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1924)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5912)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/List;
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlGeneratorImpl.createResponse(WadlGeneratorImpl.java:198)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generateResponse(WadlBuilder.java:395)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generateMethod(WadlBuilder.java:164)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generateResource(WadlBuilder.java:331)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generateResource(WadlBuilder.java:269)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generate(WadlBuilder.java:105)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlApplicationContextImpl.getApplication(WadlApplicationContextImpl.java:79)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlResource.<init>(WadlResource.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentConstructor._construct(ResourceComponentConstructor.java:198)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentConstructor.construct(ResourceComponentConstructor.java:179)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.resource.SingletonFactory$Singleton.init(SingletonFactory.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$10.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:584)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$10.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:581)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.getResourceComponentProvider(WebApplicationImpl.java:581)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiateResource(WebApplicationImpl.java:658)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.initWadlResource(RootResourceUriRules.java:184)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:162)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1298)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:169)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:775)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1583)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5670)
    ... 45 more
```

Comment: In what way does the deployment fail? What server are you deploying to?

Comment: I am getting above mentioned exception. I am deploying to glassfish 4.

Answer (score 4):

It is due to have no resource in `com.resttest.resttest` package. Your class (`resttest`)  is in `com.resttest` so, in your `web.xml`, change from this:

```xml
<init-param>  
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>  
  <param-value>com.resttest.resttest</param-value>  
</init-param>
```

To this:

```xml
<init-param>  
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>  
  <param-value>com.resttest</param-value>  
</init-param>
```

**P.S.**: Also, it seems that you're using an old version of JAX-RS. As seems to be a test to learn, consider studying the latest version.

---

**EDIT**

From [`NoSuchMethodError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html) documentation:

> Trown if an application tries to call a specified method of a class (either static or instance), and that class no longer has a definition of that method.

This is due the version of jersey. In glassfish 4 the version of jersey is 2, which doesn't have `getRepresentationOrFault` method in `Response` class. So, try to use an old version of glassfish or update the jersey version. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176811/abstractmethoderror-using-uribuilder-on-jax-rs/30177448#30177448) answer to update the version of jersey.

Comment: @simarkaur well, it is a different thing. There is something more or just that part of the stack?

Comment: I have. Please have a look.

Comment: @simarkaur yes, this is due the version of the jersey. I'll post an update.

Comment: Oh, thanks a ton. I just read it. i will try that and post back here the results :). thank you.

Comment: Than's! Update latest version of Jersey helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Produces("text/html")` and it will definitely work. Had the same issue with me as well, tried too many solutions but then got it worked with the below.

```
@GET
@Produces("text/html")
public void getUser(){
    System.out.println("Inside get user");
}
```

Java resource class

```
package com.serivce.user;

import javax.ws.rs.*;

@Path("/user/service")
public class UserServices {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public void getUser(){
        System.out.println("Inside get user");
    }
}
```

Web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.serivce.user</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It took me hours to identify the culprit. Finally, I found my method that I suspended to add resources later causing the same error as above mentioned.

```
The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes
```

When I commented below init-param included in web.xml, the error gone.

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
    <param-value>org.cnt.jsy.registrar.CaseManagementWSApp</param-value>
</init-param>
```

---

public class CaseManagementWSApp extends Application {

```
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> jsyAssets = new java.util.HashSet<Class<?>>();
        addRestResourceClasses(jsyAssets);
        return jsyAssets;
    }

    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> jsyAssets) {

          /// **NO RESOURCE ADDED HERE**

    }
}
```