# AbstractMethodError with URI Builder

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I just tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26778123/2051194) tutorial to implement a token-based authentication for my web-service and just got done with the "Securing your REST endpoints" step, but now I am always getting an AbstractMethodError, when calling my endpoints.

I already read on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30177448/2051194) that this problem seems to occur because of compatibility problems with the libraries, but the answer includes Maven, which I am not using, so I tried to exchange the libraries manually, but that did not work out and I kept getting the same or different errors.

Which libraries do I have to remove and which do I have to keep?

[image: Current Libraries]

The console output:

```
   SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet.service() for servlet [jersey-servlet] in context with path [/FM] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:662)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: You must have the SAME version of all libraries in both your development and deployed environments.

Comment: I deploy through eclipse on a tomcat server. The libraries in my build path and at the deployment assembly are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have got your issue fixed, but actual problem is

The `uri` method is an abstract method in `UriBuilder` from version 2.0 of JAX-RS specification.

You're trying to use `JAX-RS 2.0` with `Jersey 1.*`. Instead, you need to use `Jersey 2.*` that implements `JAX-RS 2.0` and contains implementation of `uri` method.

Answer (score 1):

After searching on the internet some more, I figured that to fix this error I have to include "cfx-bundle-3.0.0-milestone2.jar", which includes an implementation of the UriBuilder, into my project.