# Jersey 2.32 IllegalArgumentException jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am trying to user Jersey's JSON/bean validation however error occurs when initing servlet occurs.

Full stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.init() for servlet [rest-servlet] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(ClassVisitor.java:79)
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(ClassVisitor.java:64)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener$AnnotatedClassVisitor.<init>(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener$AnnotatedClassVisitor.<init>(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener.<init>(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:124)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener.newJaxrsResourceAndProviderListener(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.scanClasses(ResourceConfig.java:902)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig._getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:863)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:772)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1186)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.createRuntimeConfig(ResourceConfig.java:1182)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$RuntimeConfigConfigurator.init(ApplicationHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ApplicationHandler.java:290)
    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:3880)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:347)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1089)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>eu.itreegroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>admin3-iasm</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Admin3-IASM</name>

    <properties>
        <jackson.version>2.11.3</jackson.version>
        <jersey.version>2.32</jersey.version>
    </properties>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.6.3</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-ojdbc6</id>
            <name>Maven ojdbc6 Repository</name>
            <url>http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

<!-- 
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-RC1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
        -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <javaEncoding>UTF-8</javaEncoding>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Line which supposedly throws exception:

```
...
  public ClassVisitor(final int api, final ClassVisitor classVisitor) {
    if (api != Opcodes.ASM8
        && api != Opcodes.ASM7
        && api != Opcodes.ASM6
        && api != Opcodes.ASM5
        && api != Opcodes.ASM4
        && api != Opcodes.ASM9_EXPERIMENTAL) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported api " + api);
    }
    if (api == Opcodes.ASM9_EXPERIMENTAL) {
      Constants.checkAsmExperimental(this); // Line which supposedly throws exception
    }
    this.api = api;
    this.cv = classVisitor;
  }
...
```

**UPDATE:**
Using Java 8

some more text so that I could post this question some more text so that I could post this question some more text so that I could post this question some more text so that I could post this question some more text so that I could post this question some more text so that I could post this question

Comment: Which JDK are you using? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52658991/migrate-jersey-project-to-use-java-10-results-in-java-lang-illegalargumentexcept

Comment: When debugging I see that `api` parameter matches `Opcodes.ASM8`.I find it strange that `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown in line `Constants.checkAsmExperimental(this);`

Comment: Feel free to file a bug in [the Jersey issue tracker](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey) and attach a reproducer app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error did not appear anymore after I downgraded to Jersey 2.27. However...

... after this error disappeared, I got another one: [java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176811/abstractmethoderror-using-uribuilder-on-jax-rs). I had checked my pom.xml dependencies and they were correct. The problem was that I had previously had setup an Eclipse project in non-Maven manner and had simply put `Jersey 1.x` libraries (which I was initially using) in `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib` folder and I did not remove them (forgot) after I changed the project to Maven one and upgraded `Jersey` to version `2.32`. Therefore older version jars were being copied to `../ECLIPSE-WORKSPACE/.../org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/MY-APP/WEB-INF/lib` directory with `Jersey 2.x` jars. Silly me.

Having that in mind and remembering that I noticed earlier

> I find it strange that IllegalArgumentException is thrown in line
> Constants.checkAsmExperimental(this);

I think the original issue was not with Jersey version I had used at the time (which was 2.32), but with Jersey 1.x and Jersey 2.x jar files ending up in the classpath. Currently, I have upgraded Jersey version to 2.32 and everything works. So, probably there is no bug in Jersey 2.3 at all.

Comment: yes, I have faced similar problem because of both jersey 1.x and 2.x in classpath, removing jersey 1.x jars from classpath resolved it.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I was having similar error in Kafka and got it resolved because of your reply.