# Servlet.init() and load() exception when configuring jersey servlet container

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, jersey

I created my first Dynamic Web Project with a Tomcat v9.0 server in Eclipse, then I converted it to a Maven project in order to use Jersey.
I've configured the web.xml as:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/crunchify/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and the pom.xml as:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>16</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20170516</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I try to start the server I get two exceptions:

- Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] threw exception
- Servlet [Jersey Web Application] in web application [/MyProject] threw load() exception

This is the exceptions' stacks:

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] threw exception
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(ClassVisitor.java:79)
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(ClassVisitor.java:64)
    at 
org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener$AnnotatedClassVisitor.<init>(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener$AnnotatedClassVisitor.<init>(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener.<init>(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:124)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener.newJaxrsResourceAndProviderListener(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.scanClasses(ResourceConfig.java:902)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig._getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:863)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:772)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$WrappingResourceConfig._getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:1155)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:772)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1186)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.createRuntimeConfig(ResourceConfig.java:1182)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$RuntimeConfigConfigurator.init(ApplicationHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ApplicationHandler.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:4203)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:347)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1096)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5264)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1889)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:473)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1388)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:437)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:934)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)

giu 27, 2021 3:26:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [Jersey Web Application] in web application [/HandOut] threw load() exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(ClassVisitor.java:79)
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(ClassVisitor.java:64)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener$AnnotatedClassVisitor.<init>(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener$AnnotatedClassVisitor.<init>(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener.<init>(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:124)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener.newJaxrsResourceAndProviderListener(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.scanClasses(ResourceConfig.java:902)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig._getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:863)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:772)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$WrappingResourceConfig._getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:1155)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:772)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1186)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.createRuntimeConfig(ResourceConfig.java:1182)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$RuntimeConfigConfigurator.init(ApplicationHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ApplicationHandler.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:4203)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:347)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1096)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5264)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1889)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:473)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1388)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:437)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:934)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
```

In Java Build Path I have the Maven Dependencies and all jersey jars are in src -> main -> webapp -> WEB-INF -> lib.

Anyone knows how to fix them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jersey 2.32 IllegalArgumentException jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64309183/jersey-2-32-illegalargumentexception-jersey-repackaged-org-objectweb-asm-classvi)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't

Comment: You have two versions of Jersey in your classpath: one is in the `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib` folder and one is specified as Maven dependency. When using Maven the folder `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib` should be empty (or better contain only those libraries which are not in a Maven repository).