# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException caused by javax.servlet.ServletException: Error allocating a servlet instance

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I receive the following error when I try to access my localhost "Webpage". Before I try to access the site, no error occurs. I use Tomcat Embed Core Version 8.5.11, Jersey servlet container v.2.26 and Java 10. I have no clue where it comes from.

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: Allocate exception for servlet blockchain
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:171)
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:425)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener.process(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.scanClasses(ResourceConfig.java:909)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig._getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:863)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:772)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1199)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1172)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.createRuntimeConfig(ResourceConfig.java:1168)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$RuntimeConfigConfigurator.init(ApplicationHandler.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ApplicationHandler.java:313)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:4389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:313)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:282)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:370)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat$ExistingStandardWrapper.loadServlet(Tomcat.java:1020)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

These are my dependencies:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.43</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

[Error by accessing localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81dnJ.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64309183/jersey-2-32-illegalargumentexception-jersey-repackaged-org-objectweb-asm-classvi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jersey 2.32 IllegalArgumentException jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64309183) - indeed - looks similar. On a related note: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447).

Comment: You need to use a newer version of Jersey when running on Java 10 (at minimum 2.27). As an aside, Java 10 went out of support back in 2018. I'd recommend using a Java version that is actively supported, like Java 8 (old-style LTS), Java 11 (LTS), Java 17 (LTS) or Java 18 (support ends in September 2022 when Java 19 is released)