# ServletContainer class not found Exception

Tags: java, maven, jersey

I cannot compile my jersey project anymore and I get the following exception:

```
GRAVE: Servlet /Project-API threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5317)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I read on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022114/org-glassfish-jersey-servlet-servletcontainer-classnotfoundexception) that it might be caused by my pom but I cannot figure out how to fix it.

Here is my pom

```
 ...
<dependencies>

 <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>

 <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>

 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
      </dependency>

    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.expressme</groupId> 
        <artifactId>JOpenId</artifactId> 
        <version>1.08</version> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.openid4java</groupId> 
        <artifactId>openid4java</artifactId> 
        <version>1.0.0</version> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>oauth.signpost</groupId>
        <artifactId>signpost-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

web.xml

```
...
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>...</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

...
```

maven dep.

[image]

I am using Tomcat 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the minimal set up that just works for Jersey 1. Compare with your version.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"      xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
<display-name>Rest-Jersey1</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<groupId>Jersey_Maven_App</groupId>
<artifactId>com.jersey.app</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
<jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
<jersey.version>1.19.1</jersey.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    <version>20041228.180559</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<pluginManagement>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Add your repository to pull these jars.

Comment: this doesnt find jax-servlet nor javax.ws.rs

Comment: it's all in there inside bundle jar http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle/1.19.1

Comment: what does jersey-bundle include? every library with jersey*?

Comment: It includes all the dependent libraries and then you'll to include jersey run time libraries ( core, server and client( if you use jersey client). The link lists all the libraries that it includes.

Comment: I changed it but I am getting the same, please see my updates

Comment: what server are you using ? Can you share your libraries as you see under deployment folder ? Remove the jars that you don't need. Keep it simple for now until it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113908/discussion-between-eeadev-and-shiv-v).

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you solve this sort of problem. You are missing a class, so obviously you need this class in your dependencies. What dependency can you add that contains the missing class?

You can search resources like [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/search/?query=com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer) or the [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|fc%3A%22com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer%22) for your missing class (both those links search for this missing class, by way of example).

Now we know that the missing dependency is `com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet` so add this to your dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
```

By way of a suggestion, I notice that most of your Jersey dependencies are version 1.17.1 but you have one 1.19 in there ... you should probably try to stick to the same version for all of them to avoid any inconsistencies between them.

Also, if these libraries are included in your application server (like Glassfish or Weblogic, etc) then you should have `<scope>provided</scope>` on all of them. But if you're using something like Tomcat, then forget this (unless you're manually adding them to Tomcat's lib directory).

Comment: I already have this jersey-servlet dependency in my pom, I changed the different version and I will update my stackoverflow question but still no luck

Comment: @eeadev can you show your deployment folder ? the classes and the libraries. we can make sure if things are deployed correctly.

Comment: You didn't mention this dependency in the POM above. I still don't see it. (And do note that `jersey-servlet` is not the same as `jersey-server`.)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the servlet class defined in your web.xml?

It needs to be as follows for jersey 1.x versions:

```
<servlet>  
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sample.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Make sure you don't mix jersey 1.x with 2.x

You have a couple of library collisions in your `pom.xml`

- You have 2 different `javax.servlet` dependencies in your pom. Make sure you have one of them. (I'm not sure but I don't think you need to add this either as jersey would have it, check and confirm)
- Further, you have a dependency `javax.ws.rs-api`, this conflicts with
  jersey as jersey already includes it.

Even if these don't fix this particular problem, remove these collisions to avoid further issues.

for more information: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277429/exception-in-rest-jersey)
[link2](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/)