# I am trying to build an rest api using jersey. But when I am trying to access the resource , getting the following error-

Tags: jersey

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
>       javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
>       com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:669)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>       org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)

Comment: What's your jersey version?

Comment: my jersey version is 1.9....

Comment: Have you googled the error? You will get a bunch of results pointing to questions here on SO.

Comment: @peeskillet  Yes I have And the answers I got were related to - multiple version of  jersey jar in the project.here is one of the stack overflow link-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277429/exception-in-rest-jersey.But in my project I am only using jersey 1.9 . I also tried with jersey 2(glassfish version). But getting same error.

Comment: @D.R this should work for you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176811/abstractmethoderror-using-uribuilder-on-jax-rs