# Can't get Jersey dependancy to work with plain java application?

Tags: java

Continuously get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/Client at com.mycompany.app.App.main(App.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583) at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
```

All i've done is added the dependancy into the Pom file and done a mvn install and I keep getting a class error. New to Java not sure how dependancies worked i imagined it was like NPM.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>my-app</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.4</version>

</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.27</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Nulla euismod turpis quam, ac pretium purus cursus eget. Sed fermentum fermentum neque, in commodo elit blandit sit amet. Suspendisse sodales elit sodales mi varius, eu venenatis ex aliquet. Nam fermentum mi id odio finibus, vel sagittis ipsum sagittis. Suspendisse lobortis posuere leo, eget dapibus dui malesuada ut. Vestibulum semper libero diam, sed porta quam pulvinar quis. Vestibulum luctus in tellus sed semper.

Comment: I've also included: import com.sun.jersey.api.client.*;

Comment: Post the pom.xml

Comment: Pom provided above =)

Comment: Do you see the jersey jar file is downloaded inside your .m2 folder? You can find it /Users/<yourdirectory>/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-client/ and in Windows machine it would be C:\Users\{your-username}\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-client\

Comment: Yes client, core, and media are all there!

Comment: It's lorum ipsum ignore the bottom paragraph sorry!

Comment: Not sure this may lead to your issue i hope:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277429/java-lang-abstractmethoderror-javax-ws-rs-core-uribuilder-uri

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following options:

1. Set correct proxy:

   ```
   <proxy>
     <id>optional</id>
     <active>false</active>
     <protocol>http</protocol>
     <username>yourusername</username>
     <password>yourpassword</password>
     <host>company-proxy-url</host>
     <port>8080</port>
   </proxy>
   ```
2. Right click your project, choose Run As -> Maven install and then choose Maven -> Update Project
   [image]

Comment: I'm using CLI not a smart IDE :(

Comment: Also where does the proxy go in the POM?

Comment: You have to set proxy in settings.xml of maven but as you said the required jar file is downloaded then it may not be applicable

Comment: Yeah unfortunately not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with insufficient dependency . You have to add below too.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
```